# Como sumir com o efeito Parallax com angular?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

Como posso sumir com a ação do parallax quando este estiver com o um atributo?

está é a tag que possui o atributo:

```
<parallax-image ng-class="{{fixo}}" 
src="/parallax-image/assets/images/image-01.jpg"></parallax-image>
```

Este é o css que está com o atributo:

```
[class^="fixo"] {
  background-color: color($grey, 200);
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 40%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
```

E o js é este:

```
if ('.fixo' == true) {
   return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O seu uso de `ng-class` está errado. A definição correta seria:

```
ng-class="{'fixo': meuValor}" //Onde "meuValor" é um $scope do controller ex.: $scope.meuValor
```

Neste caso, a classe `fixo` será adicionado quando o `$scope.meuValor` for `true`

Outro método, caso você queira definir uma classe OU outra baseado no mesmo valor, seria:

```
ng-class="meuValor ? 'fixo' : 'nao-fixo'"
```

Neste caso se o `$scope.meuValor` for `true` será adicionado a classe `fixo`, se não será adicionado a classe `nao-fixo`.

Note então que o seu JS deverá mudar para ser algo semelhante a isso:

```
if( 'algum comparativo') {
    $scope.meuValor = true;
else {
    $scope.meuValor = false;
}
```

Como você não forneceu muita informação, essa parte da lógica depende do seu contexto, mas com essas informações creio que você consiga resolver o problema.

Comment: Ola Celsom eu coloquei desta forma:
o script está assim:
<script>
scope.haseffect = true;
scope.haseffect = (scope.haseffect === 'false') ? false : scope.haseffect;
</script>

Comment: E o html está assim:
<div ng-class="{\'parallax-image--{{index}}\': haseffect, \'fixed\': !haseffect}" ng-if="src">
        <div class="parallax-image-overlay" ng-if="alt" horizontal layout center center-justified fit>
            <p>{{alt}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>

Comment: Mas parece q o css não está carregando.

Comment: @Marcos você está colocando aquele script diretamente no corpo da página? Se sim, ele não vai funcionar mesmo. Precisa estar vinculado a um controller (ou directive - ou outro método equivalente),

Comment: Ele esta vinculado a um controler sim @CelsomTrindade...so coloquei o codigo para você ver... O script está funcionando pelo que vi no console, mas o css que criei para o fixed ele não esta retornando.

Comment: Verifique se a classe 'fixed' está sendo adicionada ao elemento. Se não estiver, certifique-se de que o valor de `hasEffect` está sendo atualizado, pois a declaração me parece tudo certo.